# Redirect POST form with headers

Tags: javascript, http

Let me explain the issue. I have an endpoint that expects a post request and returns a file. However, the endpoint is also protected by an authentication scheme that uses bearer tokens. It expects to receive the bearer token in the authorization header of the request. The question is how can I post a form with an authorization header and have the browser redirect itself to the response (i.e. have the browser download the file).

Some approaches that I have considered:

1) Manufacture a form and then submit it to the correct url. The issue here is that I cannot find a way to include the authorization header in the request.

```
form.method = 'post';
form.action = '/api' + url;
form.submit();
```

2) Use the XHR's FormData api to POST a form to the endpoint. I can easily add a header to an XHR request. The problem is that I won't be redirected in this case since it is all AJAX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dictates a request being made? Is it a user action i.e clicking a link/filling in a form?

Comment: It sounds odd that you would need to do this. You'll be putting credentials in the browser, meaning you're basically bypassing auth completely. Perhaps a better solution would be to disable it in the first place?

Comment: @Andy yes, a user action.

Comment: @moopet I am not following you.

Comment: @moopet what do you mean by "putting the credentials in the browser, meaning your basically bypassing auth completely"

Comment: You could submit the form to a local server endpoint, then have the server make the request to the endpoint that requires authorisation using cURL or something else that allows you to set request headers, then pass that response back to the original request. Downside to this is if the endpoint has a usage limit you might reach it as all requests would come from the server IP instead of each user's.